# How do I convert Console App's code block to Azure Function's code block?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, csx

I've written my sample console application and it's complied and get the data well. Now I want to test it as an Azure Function. The following are the code blocks in console app. How can I rewrite it as Azure's time-trigger function? Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;

namespace Google.Apis.Samples

internal class MyData
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Blah Blah Blah");
        Console.WriteLine("==============");

        try
        {
            new MyData().Run().Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    private async Task Run()
    {
    // I can either use service account or supply api key.
    // How do I read a JSON file from Azure function?
    // then I can Get data and display results.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the attempts you've made yourself and explain what isn't working.

Comment: So I am trying out a sample code to get data using Google's API. I use service account authentication with key info by reading a JSON file. Or I can just simply use API key to get Google's data. And now I wish to try it as Azure function. The Azure function will call the Google' Data API and display the results. The data will be parsed using Google namespaces.

Comment: I guess I just need to put all the code in console app's Task Run() function into Azure's function Run(...)  I just don't know Azure function's syntax.

Comment: Are you using VS? Which version? It should have templates for you to create a new Function app.

Comment: I will try to use a template. I was using Azure portal. I am now reading dependency injection in Azure function. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got this finally.

I used Azure Function Template in VS2017.

I need to **add NuGet Packages** (I had to use Azure V2 to match dependency requirement).
And I just have to put all the codes inside of `private async Task Run()` of *Console App* to *Azure Function*'s `public static void Run([TimerTrigger( ...`.

I have yet to publish and test it on Azure. And by the way, Azure Storage Emulator has to be initialized and started with Admin mode in Windows CMD.

[image: Function's output]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your intention, but if you want to encode your code in an azure function maybe this can help you.

in order to read a json file you can use :

```
  FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"your_json", FileMode.Open)
```

Here you code in one Azure Function

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("Blah Blah Blah");
    log.Info("==============");

    try
        {
            await Run_Function();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                log.Info("Error: " + e.Message);
            }
        }


     return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK");
}

 private static Task Run_Function()
    {
    // I can either use service account or supply api key.
    // How do I read a JSON file from Azure function?
      using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"your_json", FileMode.Open))
        {
                // then I can Get data and display results.                
        }
    return null;
    }
```